# Synchronization of Posix Pthreads not working in readers-writers problem

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, producer-consumer

I have to approach solving synchronization issues in the readers-writers problem with Posix Pthreads which I am inexperienced with.

The task consists of spawning 3 readers and 1 writer, the writer fills a queue for the readers to print. I am having trouble synchronizing access to the queue. The queue contains methods which I have tested and shown to work.

If the queue is full then it should signal the readers to read/ empty the queue. Then once its empty, the writer should begin filling the queue with random values again. Only for up to `total_tasks`.

I am mostly unsure of the proper locations the locks/ unlocks and signals are meant to go.

Currently when executing, I get the following output. It seems to be finishing the threads before anything can be done?

Thanks in advance.

```
Reader Thread 0 Created
Reader Thread 1 Created
Reader Thread 2 Created
Writer Thread Created
Reader Thread 0 Finished
Reader Thread 1 Finished
Reader Thread 2 Finished
Writer Thread Finished
<<STUCK FOREVER>>
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

int total_tasks = 0; 
int fin = FALSE; 

pthread_cond_t qEmpty = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t qFull = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void* writer();
void* reader();
```

```c
#include "rw.h"
#include "queue.h"

queue* q; 

int main()
{
    int i, j; 
    total_tasks = 15; 
    q = newQueue(5);

    pthread_t readerTID[3];
    pthread_t writerID; 

    //Create 1 Writer Thread
    printf("Writer Thread Created\n");
    pthread_create(&writerID, NULL, writer, NULL);

    printf("Writer Thread Finished\n");
    pthread_join(writerID, NULL);


    return 0; 
}

void* writer()
{
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2;
    int fin = FALSE; 

    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));

    while(!fin)
    {
        printf("w1");
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

        while(isFull(q))//While the queue is full 
        {
            pthread_cond_wait(&qEmpty, &mutex); //Wait for the readers to empty the queue
        }     

        if(num1 < total_tasks)//if we havent done all the tasks
        {
            while(!(isFull)) //If the queue isnt full - Fill with values 
            {
                printf("w2");
                num2 = (rand() % 20);
                enqueue(q, num1, num2);

                num1++;
            }

            pthread_cond_signal(&qFull); //Signal queue is full 
        }
        else
        {
            fin = TRUE; 
        }

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Should  not this `while(!(isFull)) `  be `while(!(isFull(q))) `

Comment: The outer loop of the writer function continues while 'fin' is false. The if condition "if(num1 < total_tasks)" is used to set 'fin = TRUE' when the condition evaluates to FALSE. The variable total_tasks is defined in main, but is not visible in writer. You might try moving the declaration of total_tasks to a more global location.

Comment: @DavideSpataro Thank you! I wasn't able to spot that.